# Determine the correct number of topics using latent semantic analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, topic-modeling, svd

Starting from the following example

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

body = [
    'the quick brown fox',
    'the slow brown dog',
    'the quick red dog',
    'the lazy yellow fox'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, norm='l1')
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform(body)

svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
lsa = svd.fit_transform(bag_of_words)
```

I would like to understand if there is (perhaps in scikit-learn) a way to choose the most appropriate number of topics.

In my specific case I have chosen 2 topics (arbitrarily) but I would like to understand if there is a way in Python to generalize to larger cases (with more documents and more words) and choose the number of topics automatically.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the explained variance with a range of the possible number of components. The maximum number of components is the size of your vocabulary.

```
performance = []
test = range(1, bag_of_words.shape[1], 2)

for n in test:
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=n)
    lsa = svd.fit(bag_of_words)
    performance.append(lsa.explained_variance_ratio_.sum())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(test, performance, 'ro--')
plt.title('explained variance by n-components');
```

You can see in the graph by the slope between points how much each added component contributes to the performance of your model and when no more information is gained.

[image: variancebyn]

To get the number of components where no more information is added

```
import numpy as np

test[np.array(performance).argmax()]
```

Output

```
5
```

With the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)) you can find the number of components before the largest decrease in added information

```
test[np.abs(np.gradient(np.gradient(performance))).argmax()]
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already knew the Elbow method in the case of K-means clustering. As you can see the two methods, even in this trivial example they give quite different results (3 and 5). If I were working on a bigger problem (200 documents, 10,000 words in vocabulary), what would be the best method to find the most appropriate number of topics?

Comment: In a real scenario the difference will be even larger. I would start with the elbow point to avoid overfitting to your training sample. If you want to search exhaustively for the best model take a look at [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: I'll try them both and see which one will give the most consistent results. If I consider the data frame `topic_encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(lsa, index=['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3', 'text_4'], columns=['topic_1', 'topic_2'])`, are there other ways to understand which documents "belong" in a particular topic besides the Elbow method (after having sorted the respective column in descending order of course)?